# Query logs for a specific service

Tags: xml, windows-services, event-viewer

I'm trying to query Event Viewer to bring up log events related to a specific service. 
The gui allows me to narrow the system logs to just services actions, but that's as far as I can take it. It offers the ability to query via XML but I don't know XML at all.

The specific information I'm looking for is:

-Service starts and stops for Routing and Remote Access Service
-User logins and logouts

Any help from some XML gurus?